# Object doesn't change after reassignment

Tags: python, machine-learning

I am trying to prune decision trees, using some procedure.

After i do sorts of manipulations on the current tree, i get different values from the function `validate()` (inside `prune_helper`, by `print(self.validate(validation_data))`) - before and after manipulating the tree, which is great (It means that something does happen to the tree for a given node).

```
def prune_helper(self, curr_node):
    all_err = []

    # The current tree.
    tree_1 = self
    all_err.append((tree_1._generalization_error(), tree_1))

    # Replace node with leaf 1.
    tree_2 = self._replace_leaf(curr_node, DEMOCRAT)
    all_err.append((tree_2._generalization_error(), tree_2))

    # Replace node with leaf 0.
    tree_3 = self._replace_leaf(curr_node, REPUBLICAN)
    all_err.append((tree_3._generalization_error(), tree_3))

    # Replace node with left subtree.
    test_4 = self._replace_subtree(curr_node, LEFT)
    all_err.append((test_4._generalization_error(), test_4))

    # Replace node with middle subtree.
    test_5 = self._replace_subtree(curr_node, MIDDLE)
    all_err.append((test_5._generalization_error(), test_5))

    # Replace node with right subtree.
    test_6 = self._replace_subtree(curr_node, RIGHT)
    all_err.append((test_6._generalization_error(), test_6))

    all_err.sort(key=lambda tup: tup[0])
    min_tree = all_err[0][1]

    # print(self.validate(validation_data)) <-- This

    self = copy.deepcopy(min_tree)

    # print(self.validate(validation_data)) <-- Mostly different than this

    curr_node.pruned = True

def prune(self, curr_node=None):

    if curr_node is None:
        curr_node = self._root

    # Node is leaf.
    if curr_node.leaf:
        self.prune_helper(curr_node=curr_node)
        return

    # Node is not a leaf, we may assume that he has all three children.
    if curr_node.left.pruned is False:
        self.prune(curr_node=curr_node.left)
    if curr_node.middle.pruned is False:
        self.prune(curr_node=curr_node.middle)
    if curr_node.right.pruned is False:
        self.prune(curr_node=curr_node.right)

    # We'll prune the current node, only if we checked all of its children.
    self.prune_helper(curr_node=curr_node)
```

But the problem is, when i want to calculate some value for the tree after prunning it "completely", i get the same value returned by `validate()`, which means that maybe the tree wasnt changed afterall, and the effect on the tree only took place in `prune_tree`-

```
def prune_tree(tree):
    # print(tree.validate(validation_data)) <- This
    tree.prune()
    # print(tree.validate(validation_data)) <- Same as this

    tree.print_tree('after')
```

I think that maybe the problem is with the way i try to change the `self` object or something. Is there anything obvious that i've done wrong implementing the whole thing that may lead to this results?

Comment: Assigning to `self` doesn't mutate the object. `self` behaves like any other local variable, and assigning to it just rebinds the variable, like any other variable assignment.

Comment: Yes, it can't be repeated enough: assignment *never* mutates and assignment *never copies*.

Comment: Thank you for your replies, any suggestions to overcome this problem?

Comment: If you expect the tree topology to change, then you need to reach up to the parent node and re-link its down-line references to the new leaf or sub-tree.